# Using Python to run a sourced script, cd, and then run a command within the SAME shell

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

How can run a sourced bash script, and then change directories, and then run a command, all within the same shell (Using python)? Is this even possible?

My Attempt:

```
subprocess.check_call(["env -i bash -c 'source ./init-build ARG'", "cd ../myDir", "bitbake myBoard"], shell =True)
```

Comment: change check_call to check_output. check_call exits without waiting for descendant processes, while check output waits until all output is read.

Answer (score 1):

I would make this for you, but I need to see the absolute paths. Here is an example

```
subprocess.check_call(["""/usr/bin/env bash -c "cd /home/x/y/tools && source /home/x/y/venv/bin/activate && python asdf.py"  >> /tmp/asdf.txt 2>&1"""], shell=True)
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you! Could you explain the ">> /tmp/asdf.txt 2>&1" part?

Comment: you can take out the >> /tmp/asdf.txt 2>&1 for your purposes. I took that from my crontab. what it does is cd to directory, source the virtualenv, and python script. I want to save the output to a file. >> means append. 2 is stderr 2>&1 is shortcut for 1. So it can be rewritten as: >> 1>/tmp/asdf.txt 2>/tmp/asdf.txt (to get both output and std err output and save it to /tmp/asdf.txt.